# How to perform regression algorithm on a textual data(IMDB reviews)?

Tags: python-3.x, linear-regression

```
                 reviews              label
0   i admit the great majority of...    1
1   take a low budget inexperienced ... 0
2   everybody has seen back to th...    1
3   doris day was an icon of b...       0
4   after a series of silly fun ...     0
```

I've a dataframe of movie reviews and the label column(1-postive , 0-negative review)

I've another similar test dataset with only review column

I need to build a sentiment analysis model using linear regression to predict the label column of test dataframe

Desired output: Test dataframe with label column

Regression is performed on numerical data , how do convert text review to numeric form to be able to fit it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your words to vectors, a technic known as word2vec. Here is a link explaining the [technic](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-word-embedding-model-predicting-movie-review-sentiment/)

Comment: Okay, will using td-idf also be right for conversion ?

Comment: Yes, this is also an alternative. The main advantage of world2vec is that world with similar meanings will have a similar encoding. This is specifically insteresting when you want to guess the positivity of a review. This is something you will not have with td-idf since it is only based on occurence of words.